# SVM: Why does the sign of bias $b$ in SVM literature differ?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, svm

Some sources write $wx + b = 0$ and some $wx - b = 0$ for the hyperplane. Is it just for illustration purposes where the hyperplane intercepts the $y$ axis?